# CentOS/Proftpd Directory Limit

Tags: permissions, centos, ftp, proftpd

I have a proftpd setup to use SQL for permissions (both ssh and ftp). all users user the same id. I want to restrict a particular user (client) to only LIST, STOR, and STOU in their home directory (/home/ftp/client) and not be able to LIST an /archive subdirectory.

Here's what I've got...but it doesn't seem to affect the user at all. Nothing showing in logs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Directory /home/ftp/client >
    <Limit ALL>
        DenyAll
    </Limit>
    <Limit LIST STOR STOU>
        AllowAll
    </Limit>
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ftp/client/archive >
    <Limit ALL>
        DenyAll
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does your `proftpd.conf` contain any `<VirtualHost>` sections?  If so, you may need to place the above `<Directory>` sections within a `<Global>` section, so that it applies to all vhosts.  Another possibility is your FTP client using the `NLST` (or `MLSD` or `MLST`) commands, rather than just `LIST`.

Comment: At first I did have a virtual defined but i removed it.  I placed the sections shown above in the Global section.

Comment: Are you perhaps using the `mod_vroot` module?  That can affect how `<Directory>` sections are handled.

Answer (score 0):

As Castaglia expected, the module  mod_vroot.c was the root cause for my problem, when removing the line from my config, it worked for me:

```
# LoadModule mod_vroot.c
```